# How to conditionally mutate widget based on configuration value

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm in the process of porting an M1 module over to M2 and am trying to figure out the cleanest approach for conditionally mutating a component based on a system configuration value.

In Magento 1 I did the following:

- [Use `ifconfig` in a layout.xml file](https://github.com/mpchadwick/Mpchadwick_SearchAutocompleteConfigmarator/blob/master/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mpchadwick_searchautocompleteconfigmarator.xml) to load [a JavaScript file which mutates a Prototype JS class](https://github.com/mpchadwick/Mpchadwick_SearchAutocompleteConfigmarator/blob/master/skin/frontend/base/default/js/mpchadwick_searchautocompleteconfigmarator/disabler.js).

I've read through [Magento's "use custom JavaScript"](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html) but it doesn't seem to account for this use case.

The best way I can think of to do this is...

- Add some dummy element to the document with a `data` property for the configuration value.
- Mutate the widget and use jQuery to access the value from the document.

Feels pretty dirty and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way?

Comment: First check How Magento 2 Module works & folder structure, then add your code in that. How to create Module:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/
https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-create-a-magento-2-extension/

Sample Module:- https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the config value to your JS with something like this in your template file:

```
<script>
    require([
        'Your_Module/js/your-script'
    ], function(disabler){
        disabler(<?php echo $block->getConfigValue ?>);
    });
</script>
```

In the JS file:

```
define([],
function () {
    'use strict';

    return function disabler(configValue) {
        if (configValue === '1') {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

To get the config value in your block class,

```
public function getConfigValue()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'config/value/path',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```